# Trigonometric function, with integration of definited integrals

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, integration

I have worked up to this stage of the question :

$$\int_0^{\pi/6}\frac{1-\cos2{(x/2)}}{2} dx$$

so that's where I worked up to. can someone please show me how to finish it off

Comment: What question? Show us what you have done in a clearer manner. $0$ is not progress.

Answer (score 3):

I take it that you want to integrate

$$\int_0^{\pi/6} dx \frac{1-\cos^2{(x/2)}}{2} = \int_0^{\pi/6} dx \frac{\sin^2{(x/2)}}{2}$$

Substitute $u=x/2$ to get

$$\int_0^{\pi/12} du \, \sin^2{u} = \frac12 \int_0^{\pi/12} du \, (1-\cos{2 u}) = \\ \frac12 \left [ u - \frac12 \sin{2 u}\right]_0^{\pi/12} = \frac12 \left (\frac{\pi}{12} - \frac14 \right )$$

So that

$$\int_0^{\pi/6} dx \frac{1-\cos^2{(x/2)}}{2} = \frac{\pi}{24} - \frac18$$

Comment: Thanks, I understand perfectly now!

Comment: Woops I made a slight mistake in the question. Its not a squared instead its a 2. SORRY, I feel really bad for making you explain the wrong question. SORRY again

Comment: Then ask a new question and leave this one alone.

Comment: OK. Ill post a new thread

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

$$\int\cos^2x\,dx=\frac{x+\sin x\cos x}2\implies \int \cos^2kx\,dx=\frac1k\int(k\,dx)\cos^2kx
=$$

$$=\frac1k\frac{kx+\sin kx\cos kx}2$$

and from here

$$\int\limits_0^{\pi/6}\frac{1-\cos^2\frac x2}2dx=\int\limits_0^{\pi/6}\left(\frac12-\frac12\cos^2\frac x2\right)dx=\left.\frac12x\right|_0^{\pi/6}-\left.\frac{\frac x2+\overbrace{\sin\frac x2\cos\frac x2}^{\color{red}{=\frac12\sin x}}}2\right|_0^{\pi/6}=$$

$$=\frac\pi{12}-\frac\pi{24}-\frac18=\frac\pi{24}-\frac18$$